# iOS swift: Alert when a field has no value with IF statement

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a complete novice at programming, therefore my question may come across novice also.

I have a UILabel which is populated with the users locations when they click a button.  The user is then able to SAVE all details to Parse.

```
if userLocation.text == nil {
    let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Please provide your location", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)      
} else {
    //var location = PFUser.currentUser()
    //location["location"] = userLocation.text
    //location.save()
}
```

I don't know how to say IF the UIField has no value then run the alert.

i.e. this part.

```
if userLocation.text == nil {
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that userLocation is the @IBOutlet var userLocation: UILabel!

Comment: What is wrong with what you are already saying? `if userLocation.text == nil` is a test. Of course it might be non-nil but might be an empty string `""` so maybe you want to test for that too.

Comment: Thanks Matt - "" worked a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
if userLocation.text == "" {
    // The user did not enter any text
}
```